# Reactjs export/download images for different social media platform

Tags: reactjs

I am creating reactjs app, from which i can generate  image for different  social media platforms sizes, for example facebook cover image size, user will hit click on download button and it will download  an image of the desired size.

I searched  lot but did nothing
Is there any way i can do this?

Comment: That would be done on the backend and not in the frontend, react here would only show the button, making an api call to the backend with the data, if you use nodejs you can check out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemagick

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.